# Change formatting of date to proper date format in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this column in my data frame, I was wondering how i could convert it to proper date format by %m %y, or %m %d %y.

```
  year         
 X1996.01.31
 X1996.02.29
 X1996.03.31
 X1996.03.30
 X1996.05.31
 X1996.06.30
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `as.Date`

```
df1$year <- as.Date(df1$year, format = "X%Y.%m.%d")
df1$year
#[1] "1996-01-31" "1996-02-29" "1996-03-31" "1996-03-30" "1996-05-31" "1996-06-30"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c("X1996.01.31", "X1996.02.29", "X1996.03.31", 
"X1996.03.30", "X1996.05.31", "X1996.06.30")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: @JayloyTsu i copied the format in your post.  Can you check the 'data' I updated.  It is working for me though